# How will users add extra functionality in QML based plugin system?

Tags: c++, qml, qt5.3

I've got a small application where users may create their own plugins as QML-files.
These plugins get notification upon certain events and their user-interfaces are displayed one-by-one in a TabView.

Some plugins however need functionality which can't be provided via QML like writing to files.
How would I enable my users to extend the functionality as they please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your user must:

1. Implement a QObject in C++ that provides the required functionality.
2. Subclass `QQmlExtensionPlugin` to register that QObject as a QML type.
3. Build a DLL (or SO or DYLIB) for #1 and #2, and write a `qmldir` file to tell the QML engine how to load the DLL.

***EDIT:*** Qt Creator automates a bit of this process for you. Go to "File" -> "New File or Project..." -> "Projects" -> "Libraries" -> "Qt Quick 2 Extension Plugin"

You can find more details about this process in the documentation:

- How to write a C++ plugin: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html
- Where to put the plugin files, and how to load them: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-modules-identifiedmodules.html

Note 1: Your user won't be writing a *.qml file.

Note 2: Each plugin must be in its own subfolder. This is because each C++ plugin needs one `qmldir` file, but you can't have multiple `qmldir` files in the same folder.

You can find some real examples in your Qt installation. Go to, say, C:\Qt\5.3\mingw482_32\qml -- all the subfolders here contain QML plugins, mostly written in C++. Here is some sample source code:

- C++ code for the BluetoothSocket QML type: http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtconnectivity/src/imports/bluetooth/qdeclarativebluetoothsocket_p.h.html
- C++ code that registers the BluetoothSocket type (plus other types): http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtconnectivity/src/imports/bluetooth/plugin.cpp.html

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer. It helped me a lot.
Just one more questions regarding the import path. All user-plugins have their own directory within a folder called plugins. How can I import them all at once?

Comment: See the QQmlEngine documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmlengine.html Look for functions like `importPlugin()` and `pluginPathList()`